# Why are there sometimes redundant packages in Bower?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower

There seem to be two identical packages for the Sugar javascript library, sugar, and sugarjs. Are these somehow synonyms for the same package or are they two packages erroneously maintained by two different people?

```
➔ bower info sugarjs 
bower sugarjs#*                 cached git://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.git#1.4.1
bower sugarjs#*               validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.git#*

{
  name: 'sugar',
  version: '1.4.1',
  main: './release/sugar.min.js',
  ignore: [
    '/docs',
    '/lib',
    '/script',
    '/test',
    '/performance',
    '.gitignore',
    '.npmignore',
    '.travis.yml',
    'package.json'
  ],
  dependencies: {},
  homepage: 'https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar'
}

Available versions:
  - 1.4.1
  - 1.4.0
  - 1.3.9
  - 1.3.8
  - 1.3.7
  - 1.3.6
  - 1.3.5
  - 1.3.4
  - 1.3.3
  - 1.3.2
  - 1.3.1
  - 1.2.5
  - 1.2.4
  - 1.2.3
  - 1.2.2
  - 1.2.1
  - 1.1.3
  - 1.1.2
  - 1.1.1
  - 0.9.5
  - 0.9.4
  - 0.9.3
  - 0.9.2
  - 0.9.1
You can request info for a specific version with 'bower info sugarjs#<version>'
➔ bower info sugar            
bower sugar#*                   cached git://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.git#1.4.1
bower sugar#*                 validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar.git#*

{
  name: 'sugar',
  version: '1.4.1',
  main: './release/sugar.min.js',
  ignore: [
    '/docs',
    '/lib',
    '/script',
    '/test',
    '/performance',
    '.gitignore',
    '.npmignore',
    '.travis.yml',
    'package.json'
  ],
  dependencies: {},
  homepage: 'https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar'
}

Available versions:
  - 1.4.1
  - 1.4.0
  - 1.3.9
  - 1.3.8
  - 1.3.7
  - 1.3.6
  - 1.3.5
  - 1.3.4
  - 1.3.3
  - 1.3.2
  - 1.3.1
  - 1.2.5
  - 1.2.4
  - 1.2.3
  - 1.2.2
  - 1.2.1
  - 1.1.3
  - 1.1.2
  - 1.1.1
  - 0.9.5
  - 0.9.4
  - 0.9.3
  - 0.9.2
  - 0.9.1
You can request info for a specific version with 'bower info sugar#<version>'
```

Comment: You may want to contact the maintainer and ask. Maybe it was renamed and the old name has been preserved for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Because anyone can register a package for any code at any time. So at some point along the line someone created a redundant package.

http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register